# How do I fetch data from a template on another mediawiki page

Tags: mediawiki

I have got a list of congresses. Each congress uses a template with some meta data:
http://beschluesse.spd-schleswig-holstein.de/wiki/Landesparteitag_Neum%C3%BCnster_2015

Each congress has resolutions:
http://beschluesse.spd-schleswig-holstein.de/wiki/A4:_Vereinbarung_von_Minsk_vollst%C3%A4ndig_und_konsequent_umsetzen_-_Frieden_in_Europa_sichern_(2015)

I would like to include the congresses date in the header of the resolution.

Is it somehow possible to get a value from the template on another page? How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The heavyweight extensions for sharing data are [Wikibase](http://wikiba.se/) and [Semantic MediaWiki](https://semantic-mediawiki.org/) but if you want something quick, you can just create a subpage `Landesparteitag_Neumünster_2015/data` with something like

`{{ {{{1}}} | p={{{p|}}}
|Titel=Landesparteitag Neumünster 2015
|DatumVon=20150314
|DatumBis=20150315
|Location=Holstenhallen
|Straße=Justus-von-Liebig-Straße 
|Hausnummer=2-4
|PLZ=24537
|Ort=Neumünster
|Gliederung=Landesverband Schleswig-Holstein
|Ordentlich=1
|Wahlkonferenz=0
}}`

and then invoke it on `Landesparteitag_Neumünster_2015` as `{{/data|Parteitag}}` and on the other page as `{{Landesparteitag_Neumünster_2015/data|select|p=DatumVon}}` with `Template:Select` being defined as `{{{ {{{p}}} }}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can play with the

```
<includeonly></includeonly>
```

and

```
<noinclude></noinclude>
```

tags to include only a part of your congress description into your resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [Extension:Labeled_Section_Transclusion](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Labeled_Section_Transclusion)

Put the text you want to be available on other pages between `<section begin=chapter1 />` and `<section end=chapter1/>` (change "chapter1" to anything you like).

Then just use `{{#lst:articleX|chapter1}}` where you want the text to be added.